# How can I get key prefixes of each object from a Salesforce Instance with pythons simple_salesforce API?

Tags: api, object, simple-salesforce, key

I want to extract keys for each Salesforce object (including custom) from a Salesforce environment via the simple_salesforce python library. That is, I want a pandas dataframe that looks as follows:

| object | key |
| --- | --- |
| Account | 001 |
| Contact | 003 |
| ... | ... |

For that, I connect via `sf = simple_salesforce Salesforce()`. How can I extract the desired information from this instance? Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's available as metadata of the object (type). You can call the Metadata API or use Anon Apex by combining this [Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70517/how-to-get-id-prefix-if-you-know-the-object-name/70520#70520) with [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210679/can-i-directly-call-an-apex-method-from-python-without-exposing-an-endpoint).

Comment: Seems interesting but I don't quite understand. How can I make the request to Apex via simple salesforce in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works to create the desired table:

```python
import pandas as pd
import simple_salesforce

sobjects = simple_salesforce.Salesforce().describe()["sobjects"]
key_prefixes = [[sf_obj["name"], sf_obj["keyPrefix"]] for sf_obj in sobjects]
key_prefixes_df = pd.DataFrame(key_prefixes, columns=["object", "key"])
print(key_prefixes_df)
```

Comment: Nice and concise, upvoted.

Comment: v helpful.  was able to output to a text file by adding 
```path ='keyprefixes.txt'
with open(path, 'a') as f:
    df_string = key_prefixes_df.to_string(index=False)
    f.write(df_string)```